# Cannot telnet my computer

Tags: telnet, linux-networking

A service is running in my system (redhat linux) which opens the port 9000. 
When i do
`# telnet localhost 9000`
it says,

`Trying 127.0.0.1...

Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).

Escape character is '^]'.`

But when i do the same with my network ip,
`# telnet 172.21.198.62 9000`

It says,

`Trying 172.21.198.62...

telnet: connect to address 172.21.198.62: Connection refused

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Why is that ?

I've diabled the firewall using `service iptables stop`

---

Moreover this happens only for this port, 
`telnet 172.21.198.62 22` works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process listen only 127.0.0.0:9000

```
netstat -an | grep 9000
```

change program conf